# Difference between the Munkres and Hatcher diagram

Tags: algebraic-topology

I have  some confusion  in Munkres and Hatcher Book

Right now I am trying to understand covering map . I am little bit confused in a diagram .

My confusion is   given below

[image]

**My  confusion** : Are both  Munkres and Hatcher  diagrams have same meaning or different meaning  ?

Actually  i want  to know the difference  between the  Munkres and Hatcher diagram

Comment: The Hatcher diagram illustrates a specific example of a covering map; the Munkres diagram gives a better notion of what a covering map must look like in general, without reference to any particular example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One is “local” (Munkres) whereas one is “global” (Hatcher)

If you zoom in to a small enough open neighborhood around a point on the base in Hatcher’s diagram and look at its preimage, that too will be a (large) stack of pancakes.

Basically covering spaces locally look like the Munkres diagram, and the Hatcher diagram is a particular cover $\mathbb R \to S^1$